# Which .NET data structure should I be using to associate strings with arrays of strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-structures

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and C# and I'm writing a controller that passes information needed to build a list like

```
Organization 1
    Organization 1 - Category 1
    Organization 1 - Category 2
Organization 2
    Organization 2 - Category 1
    Organization 2 - Category 2
    Organization 2 - Category 3
Organization 3
    Organization 3 - Category 1
```

where all those lines are strings. In other words, I need to associate each Organization with a list of Categories for that Organization. As of now, these organizations and categories exist in database tables, but as I extract them I need to put them in the "right" C# data structure for passing to my View.

Obviously I can do something like

```
public struct orgcats
{
    string org; 
    List<string> cats;
}
List<orgcats> oclist;
```

and append the `oclist` and pass that, but I'm sure one of you knows a better way and can educate me. I want my code to have perfect compactness, efficiency, cleverness, readability and correctness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be building out your objects to represent what they need not what they are:

```
public class Organization
{
  public string Name { get; set;} 
  public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Categories could be an `IEnumerable<string>` but as soon as you need to do one thing (like add `int Sequence { get; set; }` to Category), all your references to `Categories` become invalid and you'll have a lot of recoding to do.

I'd also suggest that *compactness*, *efficiency* shouldn't be at the top of the list.  I'd recommend Maintainability and Readability as number one(s).

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined not to make this too complicated unless you need to. If you're just passing data then a simple `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` (or `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>` or `Dictionary<string, string[]>`) would do just fine.

The other option is that if you're pulling this from a database using LINQ then there is already a built-in structure that would work fine.

```
ILookup<string, string> lookup =
    context.source
        .Select(x => new { x.organisation, x.category })
        .ToLookup(x => x.organisation, x => x.category);
```

That would then enable you to do:

```
foreach (var category in lookup["Org Name 1"]) { ... }
```